# IIS blocking WinForms invocation

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, asp.net, settings

I developed an ASP.NET web application that has the capability of invoking WinForms. Basically, I have a very close implementation of what is shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebBrowser.aspx) - I am displaying a form that is built inside the web app.

Now the problem - if I run the application in the ASP.NET dev server, it works fine. However, when I try to run it in IIS (version 6, running on Windows Server 2003 SP2), I cannot load the page. In fact, the first page loads, but the form is never invoked. Plus, I see that the browser is in constant "Loading" (as in I can see the progress bar filling halfway) state.

Could it be that there is an IIS setting that would need to be enabled in order for me to be able to run such code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I've understood what you're trying to accomplish, but there is something called "Data Execution Prevention" in Windows Server 2003.

[A detailed description of the Data Execution Prevention (DEP) feature in Windows XP Service Pack 2, Windows XP Tablet PC Edition 2005, and Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875352/en-us)

PS: Maybe you can specify where the form should be opened: on the server or on the client (embedded in the browser)?

Comment: I am trying to open the form on the client side. It is triggered by the app (so from the browser) - the user who invoked the web call should see it. Setting the DEP flag to AlwaysOff had no effect, so I would assume it's something else.